# How To Retrieve Authenticated User Inside routes.php On Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I try to access current authenticated user on routes.php, but it return null value whereas if I try to access it in a controller, the value returned normal.

```
dd(Auth::guard('admin'))->user()->name);
```

or with

```
dd(auth()->guard('admin'))->user()->name);
```

So what the best way to retrieve a current authenticated user in routes file. The purpose is simply to let's load and register some protected route only when user get logged in. The public access no need almost that route. Also this will be used to only register some services if user logged in.

Comment: You can't do that. Can you explain why are you trying to do that please? Maybe we'll be able to show you the right direction.

Comment: I wan't to load a route and service for some specific user when they are logged in. Just because we have a huge of extension that built separated both backend and frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because when Laravel processes routes files auth object is not created yet, so you'll get `null` if you'll just put something like `auth()->user()` in routes file.

Comment: So what is the best strategy to load a route and services only when certain user logged in?

Comment: As I understood you want to load some additional functionality for admin. In most cases best choice is to use separate routes and groups for admin. If you want to use same routes, you'll need to check for user role in middleware or in controller.

Comment: Yes, we apply some role and permisssion, but role and permission is to protect access to some route.

Comment: In this case, I want to absolutely include our backend extensions (load route, service provider and much) when user loggged.  This is for performance consideration because our extension causes application run slowly (about 80ms slower).

Comment: You can load your service manually in middleware where you check if user an admin or not. I guess you're using service provider, so try to register in at runtime with `App::register('YourServiceProvider');`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea, we will try combining your suggestion and some other strategy.